# How to redirect a .html file to a subfolder?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I trying to create an online multilingual cv by using html. Just I don't find any solutions how can redirect "www.cv.com/cvfiles/index_en.html" url to "www.cv.com/en/cvfiles/" ? As well with French (index_fr.html) and German (index_de.html) too...

All files of the site of my cv can find in the following folder: .../public_html/cvfiles/

Comment: So you want to change from having a trilingual site and just switch to one language with one URL?

Comment: Yes! I can do with a little trick like make en/cvfiles/, fr/cvfiles/, de/cvfiles/ folders in the public_html/ folder but is make a lot duplicates of the files. I want and need keep tidy the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite from `/xx/cvfiles/` to `/cvfiles/index_xx.html`, you must first capture the language part and then append it to the target index

```
RewriteRule ^(..)/cvfiles/?$ /cvfiles/index_$1.html [L]
```

I made the final slash optional. If you want the slash mandatory, just omit the question mark `?`, e.g. `^(..)/cvfiles/$`

---

To rewrite the other way round, just swap pattern and substitution

```
RewriteRule ^cvfiles/index_(..)\.html$ /$1/cvfiles/ [L]
```

Comment: I found an solution what is based on your code what you provided (Only virtual-folder rewriting I try to fix it first.):

RewriteRule ^en(.*)$ index_en.html$1 [QSA]

This code is working very well just found an very strange problem. When I visiting my cv at www.cv.com/en url is load correcly the index_en.html file with all images and styles what is located in the root directory. But when I add slash "/" end of the url like www.cv.com/en/ the page can load the index_en.html file just without css and images.

Comment: Following error message you can see:

The requested URL /index_en.htmlstyle/maincss.css was not found on this server.

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with relative URL to CSS and images?

Comment: Hmm... Why working without the "/" slash?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What do you mean?